# Opening a connection to multiple databases - Waking

Tags: sql-server, vba, azure, adodb

I have a large number of Azure databases, currently 6 but this will go up over time.

The databases are accessed very infrequently so for cost savings, they are set to auto sleep after 1 hour.

I need to connect to one or more of these databases in Access to retrieve data so need to wake the correct databases which takes around 30-60 seconds each.

I'm trying to add them as linked tables dynamically using `AttachDSNLessTable` however before I call this I need to wake the databases. I'd like to do this asynchronously as the waking process can take some time which will become ridiculous as the number of databases increases.

My idea was to create an array of ADODB connections, loop through the array and call the `.Open` method with the `adAsyncConnect` option, then monitor the connection state of all connections until then all come up as *Open* or have errors.

The code I have been trying is below:

```
Dim databases() As DatabaseInfo
Dim connections() As ADODB.Command
Dim drv As String
Dim i As Integer

databases = getDatabaseInfo()
drv = GetDriverName()

ReDim connections(UBound(databases))

For i = 0 To UBound(databases)

    Dim c As ADODB.Command
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sConn As String

    sConn = "ODBC;DRIVER=" & drv & ";SERVER=" & databases(i).Server & ";DATABASE=" & databases(i).Name & ";UID=" & databases(i).Username & ";PWD=" & databases(i).Password
    connections(i) = New ADODB.Connection 'Receive error 
    connections(i).Open sConn, , , adAsyncConnect

Next i
```

I'm getting a compile error on the line `connections(i) = New ADODB.Connection`, the error is `Invalid use of property`.

Does this mean there's no way to use ADODB connections in an array?
If not is there any other way to connect to a list of databases asynchronously?

Comment: It seems `Dim connections() As ADODB.Command` should be `Dim connections() As ADODB.Connection` instead.

Comment: A 5 DTU database costs AUD $8 per month for 2GB if data. If you can squash all your existing databases into one database (using schemas), then you can get a pretty low cost solution without fiddling with on demand.

Comment: @DanGuzman Wow that was it, just a typo, thank you

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Already hosting a lot of the small ones there however many of them are 2-50gb

Comment: @DanGuzman Can you post as an answer. It will help with a reporting function. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT, I posted an answer per your suggestion. I don't bother earlier since it was a just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem code:

```
Dim connections() As ADODB.Command
```

The variable name and usage indicate your intent is an array of connections so it should instead be:

```
Dim connections() As ADODB.Connection
```

This will avoid the compilation error due to attempting to assign a connection instance to a command variable.